# How do we get out of beta?

Tags: support, beta-phase

What has to happen for this site to progress beyond the beta stage?

Answer (score 5):

This site is currently in the fourth and final phase of an Area51 proposal -- beta. You can read more about this at the [Area51 faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

This is the relevant bit:

> If the site does not get used, it will be deleted.

Since this is [the second ever beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) to come out of area51, things aren't quite set in stone yet, but Jeff and Joel definitely want to see less of [this](http://gamersqna.com/), or [this](http://smartergamer.com/), or [even this](http://zergoverflow.com/).

As [our proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming) says, the site will be reviewed on **October the 5th, 2010** (90 days from the private beta start).

Comment: If you check the tooltip on the progress bar at http://area51.stackexchange.com/ it states "74% (Beta: 24%)". This with the number of days in beta being 22 indicates that we're about 1/4 of the way there.

Comment: "but Jeff and Joel definitely want to see less of <links to sites>"
I get what's wrong with the first site, but what is the problem with the other two? Too broad/specific?

Comment: @Mana: look at the timestamps. SmarterGamer e.g. has 245 questions since September 2009, we had more than one thousand in roughly 20 days.

Comment: Oh. Oh, dear. :<

Answer (score 2):

It's not that clear yet what the metric will be to determine if a site graduates from Beta.

We are the second site to reach it, so we are kind of guinea pig in this.

In my opinion, the most important thing is *traffic*, we need to make the site popular and have lots and lots of views -- I doubt they're going to compare it with stackoverflow, but they sure will compare it to other SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: I'd think gaming should have more traffic; it's a broader topic then programming imo.

Comment: it will have more traffic... in three years!